# How to handle toasts with timeout on React + NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I got a strange problem. Let's start with my stack, we're using **React + NextJS + Tailwind css** . I made an toast component using **react context**, inside my context I have methods which is managing my toasts. Now let's take a look at my code(I cant show all my code , but here is part im getting troubles with)
**Context file:**

```
export const ToastContextProvider:FC<ToastProps> = ({ children }) => {
  const [toasts, setToasts] = useState<ToastComponentProps[]>([]);

  const generateId = () => Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 9);

  const removeToast = (_id: string): void => {
    setToasts(toasts.filter(({ id }) => id !== _id));
  };

  const showToast = (toast: ToastComponentProps) => {
    const toastWithId = { ...toast, id: generateId() };
    setToasts((oldToasts) => [...oldToasts, toastWithId]);
    if (toast.timeout !== 0) {
      setTimeout(() => removeToast(toastWithId.id), toast.timeout ?? 3000);
    }
  };
```

As you can see , every toast object have a proprety name timeout , when timeout = 0 we dont have to remove it automatically by code , and user have to close the toast by himself.

**The main problem:**

I call a toasts with timeout and without , and they are deleted randomly. I have tried a lot of things but Im still stuck.